# Can you identify the plane in the picture?

Tags: military, aircraft, identification

[image]

Can you help identify this U.S. Air force four engine prop, numbered 2753.

Comment: Have picture of the plane with another called fat cat when my brother was in usaf

Comment: [This photo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F8x1F.jpg) was taken by a cousin of my mother in law somewhere in Korea in 1952. He identifies the person in the photo as Sgt. Border.

Answer (score 11):

If you blow up the photo and look carefully, the Squadron name is the USAF Bee Liners, which is the name of the 21st Air Lift Squadron.

I actually believe this is a Douglas C-54 Skymaster. You can see plane 7233-A [in this photo](http://flickr.com/photos/streamingmeemee/5560779977)

Comment: The distinctive border paint and other features seem right. +1.

Answer (score 11):

C-54D c\n 10858   type C-54D-15-DC   prod line DC589   reg\tail #42-72753 72753 (c/n 10858) to MASDC Aug 4, 1964.

- ***C-54*** is the type of aircraft (Cargo)
- ***D*** denotes improvements on the base model (C-54A,C-54B,C-54C)
- ***-15-DC*** says that the aircraft was built by Douglas Aircraft Company
- I believe the ***Prod line DC 598*** is its place on the overall
  production line.
- ***reg\tail #*** means ***42*** is the year the contract was let for the production run
- ***72753*** is the aircraft's registration number
- ***C\N 10858*** is the construction number of the Manufacturer in this case Douglas Aircraft.
- ***To MASDC*** says the airplane was sent to the "Boneyard"  at Davis Mothan in Arizona on ***August 4, 1964***.

Comment: Your answer is probably immediately obvious to an expert in the field, but not being one it took a while to puzzle out that must be its full details from some Air Force records. Would be nice if you added a sentence or two to introduce what that data is, and also where you found it.

Comment: A source would be nice. May help somebody out with a similar problem.